# I am getting compiletime error for JFUGUE in eclipse android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jfugue

The following code works well in java:

```
import org.jfugue.*; 
...............................
...............................
Player player = new Player();
    Pattern pattern = new Pattern("C D E F G A B");
    player.play(pattern);
```

But in activity in android I get the error at the last line of code 'player.play(pattern);' as:
"The type javax.sound.midi.Sequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .classfile."

Kindly help me to get this code run in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any further knowledge of Android development this leaves two possibilities:

- Dependency "javax.*" not available in your compiled version (.apk)
- Dependency "javax.*" not supported.

A quick webresearch implies the second one: https://github.com/kshoji/USB-MIDI-Driver/wiki/javax.sound.midi-porting-for-Android

Comment: I request you that provide me some link to learn to use the material you referenced above. I am a new bee in programming so kindly  help me to study to use the above alternate for "javax".

Comment: @emm Unfortunately i dont know anything about both android development and 'MIDI' stuff but here is the projects wiki: https://github.com/kshoji/USB-MIDI-Driver/wiki as faar as i understood after overflying it the "Wrapper" classes for the javx-types are needed to provide a complete USB-driver for android developpment so i dont know if it realy fits your needs.

Comment: Hi, I've also developed 'JFugue for Android' library, Its repository is here: https://github.com/kshoji/JFugue-for-Android/